# I have nested data in a JSON file and I am using a nested struct. How can I access the values that are nested within the first struct in swift

Tags: json, swift, api, struct, swiftui

**Here is my code. I am pulling JSON data from CalorieNinjas API:**

```
 struct Result: Codable {
     
     var items: [FoodItem]?
     
 }

struct FoodItem: Codable {
    var name: String?
    var calories: String?
}

 public class API {
     
     func apiRequest(search: String, completion: @escaping (Result) -> ()) {
         
         //URL
         var query = search.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
         let url = URL(string: "https://calorieninjas.p.rapidapi.com/v1/nutrition?query=" + query!)
         
         //URL REQUEST
         var request = URLRequest(url: url!, cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
         
         //Specify header
         let headers = [
             "x-rapidapi-key": "3be44a36b7msh4d4738910c1ca4dp1c2825jsn96bcc44c2b19",
             "x-rapidapi-host": "calorieninjas.p.rapidapi.com"
         ]
         
         request.httpMethod="GET"
         request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
         
         //Get the URLSession
         let session = URLSession.shared
         
         //Create data task
         let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
             
             let result = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Result.self, from: data!)
            print(result)
             DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 completion(result!)
             }
              
             
         }
         
         //Fire off data task
         dataTask.resume()
         
     }
 }
```

**this is what my view looks like:**

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var result = Result()
    @State private var searchItem: String = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .top) {
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.myPurple)
                .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter food", text: $searchItem)
                    .background(Color.white)
                    .padding()
                    .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                SearchButton()
                    .padding(.top)
                    .onTapGesture {
                        API().apiRequest(search: searchItem, completion: { (result) in
                            self.result = result
                        })
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the output to the terminal as a result of my print statement so I know my data is being fetched and stored:

```
Optional(CalorieCountApp.Result(items: Optional([CalorieCountApp.FoodItem(name: Optional("pizza"), calories: Optional(262.9))])))
```

what I was trying to do was something like Text`(result.items.name/calories)` but I am not able to access the variables like that. I am new to swift and making apps as a whole any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have a few `Optional`s in there, which means you'll probably be using the `?` operator to unwrap them.

Given your type, this should work:

```
let index = 0
let name = result?.items?[index].name // will be `String?`
let calories = result?.items?[index].calories // according to your code you provided, this says `String?` but in your console output it looks like `Double?`
```

or in your example:

```
Text(result?.items?[index].name ?? "unknown")
```

You might want to do some more reading about unwrapping Optionals or dealing with `nil` in Swift -- there are a few different strategies. For example, you can see I used `??` in the last example there.

Here's a helpful link: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/sixty/10/2/unwrapping-optionals

Comment: Wow that was way easier than I though I was forgetting that Items is an array of food items so i have to have an index thank you sir I will check mark your answer once my the timer is up.

Comment: Thanks as well for the link to resources I appreciate it I am trying to get better with swift

Comment: Glad to help. It’s a learning process for all of us